# Are there any compact php servers out there?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there are any extremelly lightweight and compact web servers with implemented PHP. For my next project I would like to find a server that anybody would be able to install and run without problems, even if they don't have much computer knowledge. And yes, I know there are a lot of LAMPs and WAMPs, but I wasn't able to find one that would suit my needs perfectly.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out: http://www.uniformserver.com/
Check out miniServers in there.

I never tried it but simple googling :)

Hope it helps and vote up if it does please :)

Comment: I'm a huge fan of WampServer as well. Very easy to install/setup. http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the newest version of PHP (5.4) comes with an embedded web server, see the release notes: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I know that, but it isn't really user-friendly and they also stated that it should only be used for testing purposes.

Comment: Well, sure but meeting your criteria " I would like to find a server that anybody would be able to install and run without problems, even if they don't have much computer knowledge" is probably near impossible (apache, nginx, *AMP, etc). I think the PHP web server is perfect - who cares if it's not production ready! Why are users that  don't have "much computer knowledge" deploying production web servers for you?!

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Mr-sk, but create a bat file with your code, and add it to windows' startup if required:

```
C:\php\php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t C:\public_html router.php
```